# Prediction model to output percentage 'likelihood'?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, sklearn-pandas

Suppose I want to predict the percentage likelihood (1-100%) that a 3rd year student graduates college.
I have a training data set with 100 observations, all of which contain examples of students classified to be "Highly likely to Graduate".
I have another data set consisting of say 500 observations (where we don't know if any have graduated).

My question is: How would I go about getting a probability value for all 500 students that describes how likely they are to graduate based on a number of features (anywhere between 1-5 features such as grade scores, living on campus or off campus, etc.) on a model that was trained from the first dataset? What approaches would you suggest?

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [OneClassSVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html#sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.decision_function) which is an unsupervised outlier detection. Since your training data contains only samples from one class i.e. "Highly likely to Graduate" training a Logistic Regression or a Neural Network may not work here. It's better to consider that whatever data you have are not outliers, and the other category which is not likely to graduate as outliers. Once you fit an OneClassSVM model you can use the [decision_function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html#sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.decision_function) to get the signed distance to the separating hyperplane, which will be positive for an inlier and negative for an outlier. Then on top of it you can just you a sigmoid function to get the probabilities out. I have shown an example below:

```
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM
X = [[0], [0.44], [0.45], [0.46], [1]]
clf = OneClassSVM(gamma='auto').fit(X)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

prob = clf.decision_function([[0.455]]) # Not an outlier 
sigmoid(prob)
#array([0.50027839])

prob = clf.decision_function([[5]])     # An outlier 
sigmoid(prob)
#array([0.11356841])
```